# Merge 2 CSV file to create one CSV file with one more column of difference

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have 2 CSV files. Let's call them `1.csv` and  `2.csv`

- The first one (`1.csv`) looks as follows:

  ```
  1,3543
  23,3632
  12,7665
  1,9795
  32,8793
  35,0290
  ```
- The second file (`2.txt`) looks as follows:

  ```
  1,4543
  3,3223
  4,1213
  6,2324
  65,3123
  32,5432
  9,9839
  5,8798
  ```
- In `output.csv` the last column is the difference between 1st column of `1.csv` and 1st column of `2.txt`

  ```
  1,3543,1,4543,0
  23,3632,3,3223,20
  12,7665,4,1213,8
  1,9795,6,2324,-5
  32,8793,65,3123,-23
  35,0290,32,5432,3
  ,,9,9839,NA
  ,,5,8798,NA
  ```

I am new in shell scripting. Please help

Comment: Hi! This isn't a free code-writing service. Please do explain what you've tried, where you're stuck, and why you don't do this is within the languages you already know (use to create this data, maybe?) but want to do this in shell scripting. Otherwise, this question seems *too broad* to me, and that'd be a close reason.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you don't have a common field to join both files. You can create one on the fly and then use awk again to calculate the differences as follows:

```
join -a2 -o auto -t, <(awk '{ print NR","$0 }' 1.txt ) <(awk '{ print NR","$0 }' 2.txt) \
    | awk  'BEGIN { 
        FS=OFS="," 
    } 
    { if ($2) { 
        $6=$2-$4 
    } else { 
        $6="NaN" 
    }; 
    print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6  
}'
```

```
1,3543,1,4543,0
23,3632,3,3223,20
12,7665,4,1213,8
1,9795,6,2324,-5
32,8793,65,3123,-33
35,0290,32,5432,3
,,9,9839,NaN
,,5,8798,NaN
```

Comment: Note that the output in the question is not from a relational join but simply from the pairing of the lines in the two files.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the two files together, you can then process the overall result:

```
paste -d, 1.txt 2.txt |
awk -F, 'NF < 4  { printf $1=="" ? ",%s,NA\n" : "%s,,NA\n", $0 }
         NF >= 4 { printf "%s,%d\n", $0, $1-$3 }'
```

This joins the two files using a comma; lines which don’t have a match in the other file will result in a short line, either starting with an empty field (if the second file is longer), or ending with an empty field (if the first file is longer). The result is processed using AWK:

- if the number of fields is less than 4, data is missing; output the line with an extra field either prepended or appended, and “NA” appended
- if the number of fields is 4 or more, all the data is present; output the line followed by the difference between fields 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
paste -d : 1.txt 2.txt |
awk -F : -v OFS=, '
{
    split($1,a,OFS)
    split($2,b,OFS)

    $1 = a[1]; $2 = a[2]
    $3 = b[1]; $4 = b[2]
}

{
    $5 = $1 == "" || $3 == "" ? "NA" : $1 - $3
}; 1'
```

This concatenates the two files side-by-side with a `:` as the delimiter, using `paste`.

The `awk` command is divided into a pre-processing block and a computation block.

The pre-processing block ensures that each record has four fields; two from each file.

It takes the two `:`-delimited fields per input line and extracts the comma-delimited sub-fields from each into the two arrays `a` and `b`.  The expected two elements from each array are directly transferred into the four first fields.  This will generate empty fields whenever one of the files is shorter than the other.

The second block computes the 5th field as the difference between the 1st and 3rd fields unless either is empty, in which case the 5th field is assigned the string `NA`.

---

Just thinking a bit about how the pre-processing block could be generalisable to any number of input files with any fixed number of fields from each file...

```bash
paste -d : 1.txt 2.txt |
awk -F : -v OFS=, -v nf=2 '
{
    for (i = NF; i >= 1; --i) {
        split($i,a,OFS)
        for (j = 1; j <= nf; ++j)
            $((i-1)*nf + j) = a[j]
    }
}

{
    $5 = $1 == "" || $3 == "" ? "NA" : $1 - $3
}; 1'
```

This fixes that itch by taking the expected number of fields in each file as the `nf` parameter on the command line and assigning those `nf` fields from each `:`-delimited input field, whether empty or not.

The computation block at the end is the same as before as we've only made the first part of the `awk` code more flexible for the possibility of changed requirements or re-use elsewhere in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
paste g1.txt  g2.txt|awk '{print $1","$2}'| awk -F "," '{if (NF==4){print $0","$1-$3}else{print ",,"$0"NA"}}'
```

output

```
1,3543,1,4543,0
23,3632,3,3223,20
12,7665,4,1213,8
1,9795,6,2324,-5
32,8793,65,3123,-33
35,0290,32,5432,3
,,9,9839,NA
,,5,8798,NA
```

Comment: You know you can ask `paste` to use a specific delimiter, right? That way you can get rid of the 1st `awk` call.

Comment: In one of Praveen’s previous attempts at answering this, `paste`’s `-d` argument was used, I don’t know why this answer doesn’t use that.